# R Failled to install any github packages (Not curl::curl_fetch_memory issue)

Tags: r, github, devtools, r-package, xaringan

I am using Windows 10 and the latest R, Rstudio, and Rtools. My R can weelinstall packages from CRAN but not from Github and get very weird message. I've looked through similar questions in Stackoverflow, github issue, and Google search and found no answers. I tried to reinstall R, Rstudio, and Rtools in different directories and different version of R and Rstudio. Nothing helps. I will appreciate if anyone can give me some help. Here is the error message I got when I tried to install `xaringan`:

```
> install_github('yihui/xaringan')
Downloading GitHub repo yihui/xaringan@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/yihui/xaringan/zipball/master
Installing xaringan
"C:/R-stabl/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file  \
  --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Yue  \
  Hu_local/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyGCl8D/devtools1c10a142590/yihui-xaringan-0453431"  \
  --library="D:/userLib" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'xaringan' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'xaringan'
    finding HTML links ... done
    inf_mr                                  html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    moon_reader                             html  
    summon_remark                           html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
ARGUMENT 'Hu_local\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmA717i\Rin254c7d787958' __ignored__

Error: object 'ÿþ' not found
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'D:/userLib/xaringan'
* restoring previous 'D:/userLib/xaringan'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

My Rtools is well installed:

```
> devtools::has_devel()
"C:/R-stabl/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD SHLIB foo.c 

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R-stabl/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c foo.c -o foo.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -LC:/R-stabl/bin/x64 -lR
[1] TRUE
```

And here's my system information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3  withr_2.1.1     memoise_1.1.0   digest_0.6.14  
[5] devtools_1.13.4
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you only intend to install the dev version of xaringan, you can do `install.packages(
  "xaringan",
  type = "source",
  repos = c("http://yihui.name/xran", "http://cran.rstudio.com")
)`

Comment: @YihuiXie, I still got an error:
`Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/R/R-stable/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\userLib" C:\Users\MYNAME_local\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2xOyJh/downloaded_packages/xaringan_0.4.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xaringan’ had non-zero exit status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this issue is found [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1693): 
It turns out being a problem of temp direction, which is probably unique for Windows. After I redirected the temp to a new direction with no space in it (in .Renviron), the problem disappeared.